# How to implement asynchronous reading in go?

Tags: asynchronous, go

I study golang scheduler in linux. I think golang using multi-thread to implement goroutine , when some goroutine is blocked in I/O(just like reading a file), other thread go on processing another goroutine . But when there is lots of I/O,I don't think thread is enough,  how golang deal with it ?

I read a article http://morsmachine.dk/netpoller , it says  “Go gets around this problem by using the asynchronous interfaces that the OS provides, but blocking the goroutines that are performing I/O.” . 
Is it  like the  aio_read ? It is said that there is lots of bugs with the asynchronous interfaces . And I don’t find it in the source code or I just miss it.

As we know ,  I understand we can use epoll to do  asynchronous io for pipes and socket, but epoll can’t be used to reading or writing of regular file.  And nodejs  use libeio to do  this for  regular file. I want to know how golang do it in runtime.

Comment: Currently, Go handles this be using threads for file reading. I've read that in Go 1.4 this issue will be addressed properly.

Comment: Node.js actually uses libuv now and this will use the appropriate OS kernel notification system e.g. `epoll`, `kqueue`, `select`, `poll` or on Windows by using an `IO Completion Port`. I would imagine Go does something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Go doesn't use anything special for file I/O yet. It just creates a new thread (so that there are always GOMAXPROCS threads available for goroutines) and blocks on the operation. I think there already was some discussion going on about using AIO on the mailing list, but there were many problems at that time. The [golang-nuts mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-dev) is probably a better place for this kind of questions.